# One user can view files in Samba share from Win7 PC, other user cannot (from same PC)

Tags: 14.04, samba

I mapped a mounted drive to a share (named "Docs") in Samba.  This drive automatically mounts.  I'm using User security for share access.  I think everything Samba-wise is set up properly, because I can access the share and all the files from the Linux box using

```
smbclient //localhost/Docs
```

and I can also connect to it from the Windows 7 laptop when I'm logged in as me (username "brant").  When using `smbclient` I'm prompted for my password, which I enter, and it works.  From the Windows PC, it just uses my Windows user password which is the same as my Linux account, so it all seems to work.

When I try to log in as my wife (username "stoners"), though, it doesn't work quite right.  From the Windows laptop I can see the Docs share, but when I try to list the files it won't let me (I get a "You do not have permission to access \Tom\Docs." error).  I can connect from the Linux box using

```
smbclient //localhost/Docs -U stoners
```

...I'm prompted for her password, which I enter, and then it seems successful - I'm looking at the smb :> prompt.  But if I try to list the files, I get an

```
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \*
```

error.

I've made the Docs folder and everything under it owned by the group "sambashare", and added both myself and my wife's username to that group.  I was thinking it must be some sort of file permission thing, since I can connect from her PC under my user name.  (Oh - yes, we both have usernames and passwords on the Linux box that match the Windows users and passwords.)

Anyway, I was hoping I could figure this out...bought a whole book on Samba server administration, which though very educational didn't quite get me there.  I don't want to use the force user option, I want this to work with our individual user accounts...

Here's my smb.conf contents, if that helps:

```
[global]
  workgroup = THESTONERS
  server string = %h (Samba, Ubuntu)

  dns proxy = no

  log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
  max log size = 1000
  syslog = 0

  panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

  security = user
  encrypt passwords = true
  smb passwd file = ./usr/bin/smbpasswd

[Docs]
  comment = Shared data on the network
  path = /media/brant/Data/Docs
  browseable = yes
  available = yes
  guest ok = no
  create mask = 0770
  directory mask = 550
  ;max connections = 3

[print$]
  comment = Printer Drivers
  path = /var/lib/samba/printers
  browseable = yes
  read only = yes
  guest ok = no
```

...and here's some permissions info.

```
dr-xr-x---+ 10 brant   sambashare    4096 Apr 20 18:26 Docs

brant@Tom:/media/brant/Data$ id brant
uid=1000(brant) gid=1000(brant) 
groups=1000(brant),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),
30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)

brant@Tom:/media/brant/Data$ id stoners
uid=1001(stoners) gid=124(sambashare) groups=124(sambashare)
```

...I had this working in 12.whatever, but haven't had any success with 14.04.  Help!  Thanks!

Comment: Arg....I mapped the share to new folder `/srv/samba/test` and everything works like a charm - I can log in and list files with either user.  But when I try the original Docs share, which again is on a mounted drive, only I can log in.  Permissions on the `test` share and `Docs` share are identical....Could this have something to do with how the drive is mounted?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is good link to show how to set up samba so can all can use it with out a log in to it.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html

-Raymond Day